# How to make div overlay another when expanding?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have two divs where someone presses a button the first div appears. I am doing it with conditional rendering in React.

```
{search && <div className='first'>...</div>}
```

The divs look like this:

```
<div class='first'>
<div class='second'>
```

When `.first` appears the other div moves to the right from the extra space. I want to make the first div overlay the second.

Also I can't use `position absolute`

Comment: `position: absolute`

Comment: I camt to do it with position absolute.

Comment: using z-index will allow you to change the layer

Answer (score 0):

You can stack one on top of the other with Grid. Here's a simple demo:

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".button");
function toggle() {
  const secondDiv = document.querySelector('.second');
  secondDiv.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
button.addEventListener("click", toggle, false);
```

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  grid-template-areas: "box";
}

.first, .second {
  grid-area: box;
}

.first {
  background: blue;
}

.second {
  background: red;
}

.hidden {display: none;}

article {margin-top: 1em;}
```

```html
<button class="button">Toggle second div</button>

<article>
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
</article>
```

The second div sits on top of the first, so ideally make that the one that appears second, but you can reverse the stacking order if you need to.

You do need the wrapper/container, though, so if that's not an option, Grid won't work.

**Edit** : I added a toggle button to show/hide the second div.

Comment: You don't need grid at all

Comment: I didn't say *need* anywhere. Just said Grid is a nice option, and the OP said `position: absolute` wasn't an option (though we don't know why).